# SQL "use" command not working in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problems getting the SQL "use" command to work in MySQL 5.7.

I have a database 'mydb' with a 'character' table.  (At the moment, the table is empty, but I don't think that should matter here).

Explicitly using "use" gives me an error:

```
use mydb;
select count(*) from character;
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character' at line 1   0.000 sec
```

However, the following line, which does not use "use", works okay:

```
select count(*) from mydb.character;
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Admittedly, I am quite new to SQL.  The full output is shown below:

[image: MySQL output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`character` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Hence you get the error when you `select` from that table. Escape with `` to avoid this. Or use names other than reserved keywords for your tablenames.

[Reserved Keywords in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Doh!  Rookie mistake.  That was it.  Thank you so much!